How to model a data object that represents a PATCH request body whose fields can be undefined, null or values
Let's suppose I need to call an HTTP API PATCH endpoint whose schema for the body is:
{
  ...
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "propertyOne": { "type": ["string", "null"] },
    "propertyTwo": { "type": "string" }
  }
}

According to the schema above, all of the following bodies are valid:
{ "propertyOne": null }

{ "propertyTwo": "test" }

{ "propertyOne": "test", "propertyTwo": "test" }

How do I model such a data object in Dart so that when I call .toJson on that object, it outputs a Map with propertyOne set to null if the property was explicitly set to null, with propertyOne set to a string if the property was initialized with a string or excludes propertyOne if no value was specified when initializing the class?
I'm currently using freezed and have a working model for the request if the schema of the API wouldn't include null as an allowed value. How I model that is:
@freezed
class PatchRequestBody with _$PatchRequestBody {
  const factory PatchRequestBody({
      @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false) String? propertyOne,
      @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false) String? propertyTwo
    }) = _PatchRequestBody;

  factory PatchRequestBody.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PatchRequestBodyFromJson(json);
}


The issue comes when I want different behaviours for when a value is specifically set to null versus when a value is not specified.
For the case above, if I run PatchRequestBody(propertyOne: "test").toJson() I get { "propertyOne": "test" } which is great. If I run PatchRequestBody(propertyOne: null).toJson() it outputs an empty object, which is not great but can be fixed by removing the @JsonKey(includeIfNull: false) annotation. This unfortunately makes the case where I run PatchRequestBody(propertyTwo: "test").toJson() output { "propertyOne": null, "propertyTwo": "test" } which is not what I desire.
I tried looking for some solutions and found this Optional class from a package called quiver but it seems like they advise against not using it anymore.
Otherwise I couldn't really find a way to solve or model this.

Would you consider { "propertyOne": null } to be the same as {}? Why? Why not?

Wouldn’t consider them the same, the first body would instruct the backend to set the property to null while the second one wouldn’t have any effect.

If you only have a few classes to encode, you could do them by hand, for example:
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print(json.encode(PatchRequestBody()));
  print(json.encode(PatchRequestBody(propertyTwo: 'test')));
  print(json.encode(PatchRequestBody(
    propertyOne: 'test',
    propertyTwo: 'test',
  )));
}

class PatchRequestBody {
  const PatchRequestBody({
    this.propertyOne,
    this.propertyTwo,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    if (propertyOne == null && propertyTwo == null) {
      // special case if both null - emit first property as null
      return <String, dynamic>{'propertyOne': null};
    }
    final m = <String, dynamic>{};
    _addIfNotNull(m, 'propertyOne', propertyOne);
    _addIfNotNull(m, 'propertyTwo', propertyTwo);
    return m;
  }

  void _addIfNotNull(Map<String, dynamic> m, String name, String? val) {
    if (val != null) {
      m[name] = val;
    }
  }

  final String? propertyOne;
  final String? propertyTwo;
}


Hmm, maybe I wasn’t too clear in my expectations, if both values are null it means the object could’ve been instantiated either by calling PatchRequestBody() or PatchRequestBody(propertyOne: null). I would like to differentiate between these 2 cases.

I think I could manually implement those classes and have their default value be something like an “undefined” class instance by convention. Then exclude values based on whether they are undefined or not, but I was wondering whether there are any solutions which involve less maintenance and boilerplate code.

The fundamental problem is that you cannot tell the difference between the default value null because nothing was specified and the null you actually specify. If you knew that the string property would never be "null" you could detect the value "null" and add the property to the map as null. You won't find a code generator (e.g. freezed) that copes with the difference between your two nulls.

Understood, thank you for taking your time!
